# Restrict laravel to open url that is not in route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am Learning laravel now.

Today I came across a problem that surprised me.
I open this link in my browser:
http://localhost/laravel/project/ch/resources/views/pages/blog.blade.php
And I expect error 404. but it opens contains of this file.

So, How to restrict laravel to do this.

I want laravel to open only url mentioned in routes.otherwise error 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you access your site from `http://localhost`. Every file and folder that is inside your root folder is accessible via the browser.

So don't run your project from localhost but from a proper virtual host. For example make `http://project.dev` and use that to access your site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/laravel/project/public"
   ServerName project.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

That way you won't be able to access `resources/views` because it is outside of your document root. (one folder higher than public folder)

You can also upload your site to a webhost and see that you won't be able to access files and folders above your public folder in the browser.